# UIApplication.shared.applicationIconBadgeNumber is laggy

Tags: ios, swift, uiapplication

I'm building an iOS app, and I noticed something odd - 
sometimes, the line of code

`let someVariable = UIApplication.shared.applicationIconBadgeNumber`

is extremely laggy (taking on the order of seconds to complete), and sometimes it is not. Is there a reason for the variation in times this line of code takes to complete? It seems like a simple assignment, so I'm a bit confused about why it would take so long.

Comment: How do you measure performance?

Comment: The main thread of the app freezes for ~5 seconds after i check with a breakpoint before and after the line of code

Answer (score 0):

If you care about performance of your app, then you can't measure it with debugger attached and in Debug configuration, since it has additional overhead.
Instead try new Signpost with Instruments [article](https://pspdfkit.com/blog/2018/using-signposts-for-performance-tuning-on-ios/)

If you care only in duration while debugging, then I could guess it affected by communication with `Springboard` process + debugger protection. But I would say it mean nothing in general.

Comment: The performance of the app isn’t materially impacted by the debugger in this case. I checked using a timer and it’s on the order of ~4 seconds for this single code to execute. I’m just confused why this would take so long to work considering it’s only getting the value of a variable

Comment: @JohnDoe please provide more information how you measure it with timer? Do you mean time profiler? Or have you tried proposed by me `os_signpost`?